# Как в Delphi использовать исходники на C/C++?

Tags: delphi

Есть набор исходников на C/C++.
Как можно их использовать в Delphi?
Может как-то скомпилировать и подключить объектные файлы?
Какие есть способы?

Comment: Компилируете компилятором c|c++. Предварительно подогнав соглашения о вызовах функций. Хотя дельфи и сам имеет широкие возможности по подгонке со своей стороны. С какой стороны удобнее, с той и подгоняете. На дельфи составить юнит с импортом функций из c. Этот процесс был хорошо описан в документации. Весь winapi таким же способом импортирован в дельфи (за тем исключением, что исходников нет и компилировал их кто-то другой)

Answer (score 4):

Так выглядит текст на C++

```
extern "C"
{
    HWND ShowReport(const char* host,
                    const char* base,
                    const char* login,
                    const char* pasword,
                    const int32_t id,
                    const int32_t argc,
                    const char** argv
                   )
    {
        ///......
        return hWnd;
    }

}
```

Обертывание в `extern "C"` нужно для того, чтобы C++ не выполнял для этой функции `name mangling`, и в dll она называлась точно также, как у нас в исходнике. Обратите также внимание, что для числовых типов жестко указаны длины в битах - `int32_t` - чтобы гарантировать совпадение с типами `Delphi`

Прототип этой функции для `Delphi`:

```
function ShowReport(
host:PAnsiChar;    
base:PAnsiChar;
login:PAnsiChar;
passwd:PAnsiChar;
id:longint;
argc:longint;
argv:PPAnsiChar):hwnd;cdecl;external 'showreport.dll' name 'ShowReport';
```

Указаны те же параметры, кроме того, указано соглашение о вызовах - [`cdecl`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5#cdecl) и имя файла dll - `showreport.dll` и отдельно указано название функции - `ShowReport`

Полезный инструмент при работе с `dll` - [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

[image: Dependency Walker Window]

Он выводит список всех функций, которые можно импортировать из `DLL`, а также список всех ее зависимостей.

Answer (score 4):

Есть 3 варианта:

1. Cкомпилировать код в виде внешней `dll` и переписать заголовочники с объявлением экспортируемых функций с Си на Delphi. Обычно, так возможно использовать только Си код, но если сильно захотеть и немало извернуться, то можно и С++: [Using C++ objects in Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html).
2. Сишным компилятором из поставки RAD Studio, скомпилировать Си код в объектные файлы `*.obj`, переписать объявление функций и дописать недостающие функции из стандартной библиотеки, которые, возможно использует сишный код. К примеру, именно так в Delphi используется `zlib`, а в [mORMot](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki/Synopse+OpenSource) даже `SQLite3` [умудрились прилинковать](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SynSQLite3Static.pas). Но не каждый код получится без проблем так скомпилировать, из-за особенностей компилятора и поддержки стандарта Си. Как это делается: [Using C object files in Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cobjs.html) (пишут, что начиная с `XE2` можно даже линковать объектные файлы скомпилированные не в RAD Studio). Про С++, опять же, лучше сразу забыть.
3. Полностью портировать код на Delphi.